# Guessing the correct instance of Num from the context

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-systems

Suppose:

```
import Data.Int (Int64)

data Unknown

class Meh a where
    meh :: a -> String
instance Meh Int64 where
    meh = show
instance Meh Unknown where
    meh _ = "Unknown"
```

It is obvious that `meh` can only take either an `Int64` or an `Unknown`.

But we all know that

```
meh 1
```

will cause an error (No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal '1') because `1` is `Num a => a` and compiler doesn't know which instance of `Num` it should be.

However, it should (logically) be possible to infer `1` to be an `Int64` because it is passed to `meh` and `meh` can only take either an `Int64` or an `Unknown`. In other words, it should be possible to calculate the "intersection" of `Num` and `Meh` and decide which instance `1` is.

So my question is: Do you know any way (compiler extension, code workaround, anything) that makes it possible to write `meh 1` where `1` is correctly inferred to be an `Int64` without adding type signatures or adding specialised functions?

Comment: You could try the [`default`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#default) keyword and set it to `Int64`, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for giving me the opportunity to look into what the `default` keyword does. Unfortunately it seems to be a module-level keyword, not suited for what I want (have a polymorphic library function to which you can pass numeric literals without adding type signatures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying your example in GHC 7.8.3

```
>>> meh 1
```

I get:

```
<interactive>:2:1:
    No instance for (Meh a0) arising from a use of ‘meh’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Meh Unknown -- Defined at Meh.hs:9:10
      instance Meh Int64 -- Defined at Meh.hs:7:10
    In the expression: meh 1
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = meh 1

<interactive>:2:5:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal ‘1’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
    ...
```

This is because compiler tries to typecheck:

```
>>> meh (fromInteger (1 :: Integer))
```

For which you get similar errors:

```
<interactive>:4:1:
    No instance for (Meh a0) arising from a use of ‘meh’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Meh Unknown -- Defined at Meh.hs:9:10
      instance Meh Int64 -- Defined at Meh.hs:7:10
    In the expression: meh (fromInteger (1 :: Integer))
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = meh (fromInteger (1 :: Integer))

<interactive>:4:6:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of ‘fromInteger’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
```

---

Type-classes are open. No-one restricts someone else defining:

```
newtype MyInt = MyInt Int deriving (Num)
instance Meh MyInt where
   meh = ...
```

Then even in your example `meh 1` can be resolved to `(meh :: Int64 -> String) 1`, generally it can't. Arguments like "but based on the `Meh` instances visible in the scope" doesn't really work in Haskell, as instances are global.

---

If you define `data` (which is closed), then using `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` you could do:

```
data Meh = MehInt Int64 | MehString String

instance IsString Meh where
   fromString = MehString
```

Then

```
"foo" :: Meh
```

will compile, as GHC "will see"

```
fromString "foo" :: Meh
```

Similarly you can define incomplete `Num` instance, with only `fromInteger` defined. Yet I personally dislike incomplete instances, though this case is handy when defining eDSLs.

Comment: I'm completely failing to grasp how `newtype MyInt = MyInt Int deriving (Num)` can help me deal with the type variable ambiguity error. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Minoru, it doesn't help. I tried to clarify that part of the answer.

Comment: I see. Thanks for such a great answer anyway.